# Configure Apache to forward requests to proxy with NTLM2 authentication

Tags: authentication, ntlm

I'm trying to call a REST API over the internet using SoapUI but I'm behind a corporate firewall that uses NTLM2 authentication which is not supported by SoapUI.

Is it possible to run a local Apache or ISS instance to forward the request and add the authentication?

Answer (score 2):

Try [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) or [ntlmaps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/).